# How to compose two UIImage objects into one UIImage outside of -drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a few UIImage objects which I want to compose into a single UIImage and then save it to disk. I'm not displaying this on the screen so it doesn't make sense to do it in -drawRect.

Is there a way of creating a context similar like in `-drawRect:` and then just draw the UIImage objects in there using something like `CGContextDrawImage(context, imgRect, img.CGImage);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to use a [CGContextRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to draw all the images in at the desired place and then get the resulting image. The code will look something like this:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, desired_width, desired_height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image));
//This code is to ilustrate what you have to do:
for(image in your Images) {

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(currentImage.frame.origin.x, currentImage.frame.origin.y, CGImageGetWidth(currentImage), CGImageGetHeight(currentImage), currentImage);
}

CGImageRef mergeResult  = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

mergedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:mergeResult];
CGContextRelease(context);
CGImageRelease(mergeResult);
```

Answer (score 4):

CGContextRefs can be created whenever you wish and this allows you to do all kind of image manipulations.

Use CGBitmapContextCreate to create context and CGBitmapContextCreateImage to get final result.